# How to sort DatagridView that is bound to DbSet Collection in order of clicked column header value

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have implemented a windows form application that connects to a remote mysql database using the Entity Framework library and when I first display the form by setting the datasource, the data displays correctly. However, when I click the column header, it does not sort the data in ascending or descending order.

Further info:

I set the datasource for the datagridview using:

```
using (databaseContext db = new databaseContext())
{
    myDataGridView.DataSource = db.someTable.ToArray();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in myDataGridView.Columns)
    {

        myDataGridView.Columns[column.Name].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    }
}
```

This code is executed on the listLoad event for the form I am trying to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Automatic` sort mode work for you, you need to use an implementation of `IBindingList` which supports sorting.  Using Entity Framework, [`ToBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575(v=vs.103).aspx) method of the [`Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.113).aspx) property of `DbSet<T>` returns a sortable `BindingList<T>`:

```
//using System.Data.Entity;
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    db.SomeTable.Load();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = db.SomeTable.Local.ToBindingList();
}
```

**Note:**
You should first Load data into `DbSet` by calling `Load` or `ToList()` to enumerate the `IQueryable` and convert it to actual data. Then the data is in the Local property.

[`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.load(v=vs.113).aspx) is an extension method on `IQueryable` and is equivalent to calling `ToList` and then throwing away the list without the overhead of actually creating the list.

Comment: I tried using that and now when I display the form, it's not displaying the data that is ion the table itself.

Comment: You should load data first. Probably you forget to load data.

Comment: You should first `Load` data into `DbSet` by calling `Load` or `ToList()` to enumerate the IQueryable and convert it to actual data. Then the data is in the `Local` property.